# Can you take large umbrellas on a plane?

Tags: aircraft, prohibited-items

By large umbrellas, I mean the non-collapsible ones that look like these :

[image]

Will there be any issue with bringing around a long, pointy object on aircraft?

Comment: which country/airline are you planning on doing this with?

Comment: @MarkMayo, I didn't specify that as I typically don't stick with one airline. Most of my destinations are in Asia/Australia though, and my origin country is Australia.

Comment: Slight problem with that is different airlines might have different policies :/ Especially the LCCs who tend to be very strict on luggage.

Comment: Isn't that a collapsable umbrella? It looks like a normal sized one.

Comment: Even if allowed, by the time you arrive at the airport [it may not be in good shape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4jS256kTTQ)

Comment: I presume you mean bring it onto the plane as carry on?  It depends on the airline and potentially the enforcement by staff.  If you can fit it into your check-in luggage then no problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't be sure of it. I've had an umbrella like that confiscated by security in Brussels Charleroi.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the airline, as do some other allowed/prohibited items.  (For example, the TSA changed the rule prohibiting cigarette lighters some years ago, but some airlines still do not allow them.)  As for umbrellas, United allows them.

Comment: What does the airline have to do with what's allowed? It would be handled by airport security, not the airline. Except for hand luggage size constraints, but that's not what's being dicussed here.

Answer (score -1):

It won't be an issue due to pointiness.  Knitting needles are allowed too, and they're even pointier.  The only possible issue would be if the overall length is deemed excessive...which is unlikely on a regular commercial flight.  Worst case the crew might ask to take it from you and store it in their "closet" on board.

Comment: [At least one  case in this thread](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g298309-i9318-k1368811-Is_umbrella_allowed_in_cabin_baggage-Kuching_Sarawak.html) of umbrellas not being permitted

Comment: This is almost certainly at the security agent's discretion so a blanket statement that umbrellas (or indeed knitting needles) are allowed doesn't have much value.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Knitting needles are *explicitly called out as *allowed* in the TSA's own guidelines (which are followed by many other countries as well).  It isn't ambiguous or unclear, they are allowed.  If a security agent doesn't play by the rules, well, they could take almost anything away from you.