# Small umbrella in the carry-on bag?

Tags: aircraft, prohibited-items

I am planning my next trip and I was wondering whether I could have a small umbrella in my carry-on baggage:

[image]

Is it the same as carrying a [large umbrella](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56701/can-you-take-large-umbrellas-on-a-plane) ?

Comment: It's different from a large umbrella since a large umbrella is unlikely to fit inside a carry-on bag.

Comment: I adjusted the header to read the same as the body of the question, Carry-on. It is not going to be a problem in your checked-in luggage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering whether I could have a small umbrella in my carry on baggage:

I have routinely carried (as part of cabin luggage) the like pretty much all round the world and nothing at all has ever been mentioned about it.

> Is it the same as carrying a large umbrella?

No, because cabin luggage may have a maximum dimension as well as maximum of the sum of all dimensions and, frankly, in a confined space like a cabin traditional umbrellas can be a nuisance. However, I think most airlines will accept traditional umbrellas as a 'personal item' over and above hand carry-on ([example](https://www.iapa.com/index.cfm/travel/blog.article/blog/community/art/Just-what-exactly-is-that-one-personal-item-youre-allowed-onboard?C=1)). Though more likely the full-service carriers and to or from wet climates. They may take it off you as you board and store it in a cupboard separate from the overhead lockers.

Comment: Yes, i have seen full size umbrellas in the cabin.  They either go in the closet or longways in the overhead.

Comment: Whether or not the airline accepts it [may be irrelevant](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56701/819).